# Python: update dictionary key with tuple values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary that has keys with two values each. I need to update the second value as pass duplicate keys. 
Clearly what I'm trying isn't working out.

---

```
if value1 not in dict.keys():
    dict.update({key:(value1,value2)})
else:
    dict.update({key:value1,+1)})
```

this just returned a diction with 1s for value 2 instead of incrementing by 1

Comment: It's not quite clear from your question what your intended result is - what should happen when `value1` is already a key in `dict`?

Comment: value1 I want to stay the same. I just want to increment value 2. Value2 is just a counter for how many times that the key is compared to dictionary when the key already exists

Comment: Your question does not make sense, if value1 is supposed to be a part of the value tuples, then why are you searching for it in dict.keys(). Also tuples are immutable in Python, so if you want to update a value inside a tuple you will have to create a new tuple with the required values and replace the existing tuple with the new tuple in the dictionary, Maybe try to add a example with values to explain what functionality you expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `+1` doesn't increment anything, it's just the number 1

Also avoid using `dict` as a name because it's a [Python built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)

Try structuring your code more like this:

```
my_dict = {} # some dict
my_key = # something

if my_key not in my_dict:
    new_value = # some new value here
    my_dict[my_key] = new_value
else:
    # First calculate what should be the new value

    # Here I'm doing a trivial new_value = old_value + 1, no tuples
    new_value = my_dict[my_key] + 1
    my_dict[my_key] = new_value

    # For tuples you can e.g. increment the second element only
    # Of course assuming you have at least 2 elements,
    # or old_value[0] and old_value[1] will fail
    old_value = my_dict[my_key] # this is a tuple
    new_value = old_value[0], old_value[1] + 1
    my_dict[my_key] = new_value
```

<sub>There may be shorter or smarter ways to do it, e.g. using the operator `+=`, but this snippet is written for clarity</sub>

Comment: If I were able to just grab the tuple of the key im checking. Would i be able to just increment the second value and then update the dictionary?

Comment: Yes I just had read your comment in the question, see the example that increments the second element in the tuple :)

Comment: seems like a dumb question I should know the answer to, but how do I accept the answer...nevermind got it.